# Value is not passed on javascript code in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am new to django and javascript both. And I am using highcharts for displaying charts. My problem is at template file.

**visualise.html contains**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yname_agewise_total_call_duration = {{ yname.agewise_total_call_duration|safe }};
    var yname_agewise_weekly_total_call_duration = {{ yname.agewise_weekly_total_call_duration|safe }};
</script>
```

I tested the value of `yname.agewise_total_call_duration` 
and `yname.agewise_weekly_total_call_duration` in my html file it shows well. But when I want to use that value `yname_agewise_total_call_duration` and `yname_agewise_weekly_total_call_duration`

in javascript file charts.js it cannot show the values.
I tried in **charts.js** as

```
alert(yname_agewise_total_call_duration);
```

the popup displays undefined.

What is the problem here ? How to solve it ?

Comment: your js file does not have the context of django template variables. you can only access it in the html files

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. You can't serve JavaScript `files` that should be compiled with Django variables. This is bad practice and will lead you down a very hairy path.

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of `visualise.html`?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value. Check on your browser console whether **yname_agewise_total_call_duration** holds any data or not